# Error running java code in netbeans

Tags: java

I was writing some class called events and implementing some methods inside this class. for some reason while running the program from main the program stops after the user enters a start date and a message build successful is displayed. so it skips the other code below that.

Here is the code:

```
    public void CreateEvent(){

    try{

        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        event MyNewEvent = new event();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();   
        JDBC MyJDBC = new JDBC();
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;


        //getting inputfrom the user
        System.out.print("Event Name \n");
        MyNewEvent.EventName = inFromUser.readLine();

        System.out.println("Kindly Provide the start date(Format dd MM yyyy HH:mm)");
        //parsing date from user using SimpleDateFormat
        date = sdf.parse(inFromUser.readLine());
        System.out.println("Kindly Provide the end date(Format dd MM yyyy HH:mm)");
        MyNewEvent.startDate = date.toString();

        System.out.println("Kindly Provide the end date(Format dd MM yyyy HH:mm)");
        date = sdf.parse(inFromUser.readLine());
        MyNewEvent.endDate = date.toString();

        MyNewEvent.CheckDate(MyNewEvent, sdf, inFromUser);

        System.out.println("Where is the event:");
        MyNewEvent.Location=inFromUser.readLine();

        System.out.println("Description");
        MyNewEvent.Description= inFromUser.readLine();


    }
    catch (IOException ex) {//catch the exception

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {

        ;
    }

}
```

Comment: And is there an error in the stack trace?

Comment: What have you attempted in the way of debugging? Have you tried to output the `ParseException` if it is caught?

Comment: i am still new to java and to netbeans, and i don't know how to use the debugger yet. It would be really helpful if i did

Comment: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/debug-visual-screencast.html

Comment: I figured out how to print the stack trace and i figured out that i was inputing the date in a format different to the one specified in SimpleDateFormat. I feel so stupid. Thank you guys and i will read the link to learn how to debug :)